# Finding an associated job with a package

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

So I have created a simple job in the Sql Server Agent that runs a SSIS package every 5 minutes, however
I have been struggling to find the relationship between the Sql Server Agent job and its associated Package, Since there is no job_id in the dbo.sysssislog table that connects the job with a specific package. I either want to retrieve the job_id in the SSIS package so I could log it in the Database somewhere or a simple query in the SQL Server which defines the relationship between the two

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Not sure quite what you're trying to do here.  Do you want a sql statement that gives you the job and package?

Comment: Hi @paqogomez thanks for your quick reply, sorry for the confusion I edited my question so its more clear now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no relationship. I can run an SSIS package via dtexec via xp_cmdshell which will still log to sysssislog but there wouldn't be a job_id associated to it.

You *might* be able to tie the job step start time to the package's `PackageStart` event but it's going to be imprecise as there might be a delay in the executable actually starting. Plus, the stupid way they store date and time separately in the sys job tables.

Come 2012 and the project deployment model, you can actually access a system Variable that is the package execution id (they call it differently) when it was ran on the server.

Comment: thanks @billinkc , there goes my two hours of frustration, Unfortunately the place I work at does not hold the license for the 2012 version otherwise I would have :(